Receiving "403 Forbidden" Error When Sending API GET Request in Odoo Using Postman
I'm trying to send a GET request to my Odoo API endpoint using Postman, but I'm encountering a "403 Forbidden" error. Here are the details of my setup:

Odoo Version: [ Odoo 15 community]

API Endpoint: http://localhost:8069/api/postman

Authentication: I'm using Basic Authentication with the following credentials:

Username: [admin] it is my odoo username

Password: [ admin] it is my odoo password




This is the full error message I receive when I click send: xml
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.</p>

Here’s the relevant part of my Odoo controller where I defined the route:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import http

class TestApi(http.Controller):
    @http.route("/api/postman", methods=["GET"], type="http", auth="basic", csrf=False)
    def test_endpoint(self):
        return "This is a test API endpoint with basic authentication."


Steps I’ve Taken:
I have verified that my user credentials are correct.
The user has the necessary permissions to access the API.
The API endpoint is correctly configured to use Basic Authentication.

Your problem is the auth="basic". This is not a recognised authentication method for Odoo. Odoo's @http.route only accepts 'user', 'public' or 'none'. You can check the usage documentation on odoo/odoo/http.py:route() method.

"I want to use basic authentication. If I set auth="public" or auth="user", no authentication is applied, allowing me to send requests without a username and password."

Erase in odoo doesn'T really support the authentication you want. This code just isn't there.
The ode has its own authentication option. When you set "user" it turns on. It consists in the fact that you must first receive a cookie. And then in the postman already pass these cookies in the cookie header. I am sending examples of authentication and subsequent requests from my mobile app. I think it will be clear to you and you will transfer it to the postman.

next how use this cookie

So you can'T get the data in one request. First you need to get a cookie(token). And then make a request with this cookie. Also note that cookies also come in the set-cookie header By the way, there is another alternative option to create an API KEY in the user's settings and use it.
If you want implement basic auth on your custom controller you should do like this. This is my implementation of the basic.



"I need code that complements my existing code rather than new code."

Basic auth not supported odoo, your code cant work...

what about JWT Code Implementation in Odoo API?
